# How to find which project or which file uses the unsafe function call through warning c4996

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Warning 1   warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility   2227

Assume that one solution has the following structure:

```
Solution
 - MainProject
 - Project1
 - Project2
 - Project3
 - Project4
```

Where The Main Project depends on Project1&4, Project1 depdents on Project 2&3. When the dependency gets complicated, it is really tedious and difficult to figure out which project compilation causes the warning.

**Question**> Is there a way that VS can tell me which project or which file that includes the unsafe function call? For example, does VS provide a switch that can print the build path?

For example:

> Warning   1   warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with
>   parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to
>   check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use
>   -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\xutility  2227

Answer (score 0):

When I have a problem like that I use "search in files" in Visual Studio.

Select "Edit->Find and Replace->Find In Files", in the dialog that appears enter the path to the common root of all projects in "Look in" and enter the function name in "Find what".

Comment: This is exactly what I have done when I first ran into this problem. I searched `xutility` through my whole solution but nothing is returned.

Comment: Is `xutility` an offending function?

Comment: We don't use it in our project. Also I update my OP with a warning message.